# Isabelle equivalent definitions treated differently by auto

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to add some small improvements to `Jacobson_Basic_Algebra`.

ORIGINAL DEFINITION:

Their definition of monoid isomorphism is as follows.

```
locale monoid_isomorphism =
  bijective_map η M M' +  source: monoid M "(⋅)"  + target: monoid M' "(⋅')" "'"
  for η and M and composition (infixl "⋅" 70) and unit ("")
    and M' and composition' (infixl "⋅''" 70) and unit' ("''") +
  assumes commutes_with_composition: "⟦ x ∈ M; y ∈ M ⟧ ⟹ η x ⋅' η y = η (x ⋅ y)"
    and commutes_with_unit: "η  = '"
```

and then they have a theorem that the inverse mapping is also an isomorphism

```
theorem inverse_monoid_isomorphism:
  "monoid_isomorphism (restrict (inv_into M η) M') M' (⋅') ' M (⋅) "
  using commutes_with_composition commutes_with_unit surjective 
  by unfold_locales auto
```

MY DEFINITION 1:

So I added my improvement by splitting the definition into two parts. First I define morphism
as a function that satisfies `f (a b) = f(a) f(b)`.

```
locale monoid_morphism = (* This is like homomorphism but lacks the commutes_with_unit axiom *)
  map η M M'+  source: monoid M "(⋅)"  + target: monoid M' "(⋅')" "'"
  for η and M and composition (infixl "⋅" 70) and unit ("")
    and M' and composition' (infixl "⋅''" 70) and unit' ("''") +
  assumes commutes_with_composition: "⟦ x ∈ M; y ∈ M ⟧ ⟹ η (x ⋅ y) = η x ⋅' η y"
```

then I define isomorphism as a morphism that us bijective

```
locale monoid_isomorphism = monoid_morphism + bijective_map η M M'
```

and then I prove that neutral element must map to neutral element `f(1)=1`

```
begin monoid_isomorphism context                               
theorem commutes_with_unit: "η  = '"
proof -
  {
    fix y assume "y ∈ M'"
    then obtain x where nxy:"η x = y" "x ∈ M" by (metis image_iff surjective)
    then have "η x ⋅' η  = η x" using commutes_with_composition[symmetric] by auto
    then have "y ⋅' η  = y" using nxy by auto
  }
  then show "η  = '" by fastforce
qed 
end
```

so in this way, I can remove the superfluous axiom from the definition and make it into a theorem instead.

THE PROBLEM:

So all in all, the two locales are not only equivalent but actually look exactly the same from outside. But somehow the `inverse_monoid_isomorphism` proof fails now.

```
theorem inverse_monoid_isomorphism:
  "monoid_isomorphism (restrict (inv_into M η) M') M' (⋅') ' M (⋅) "
  using commutes_with_composition commutes_with_unit surjective 
  apply(unfold_locales)
  apply(auto)
```

yields

```
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀xa xb.
       (⋀x y. x ∈ M ⟹ y ∈ M ⟹ η (x ⋅ y) = η x ⋅' η y) ⟹
       ' = η  ⟹ M' = η ` M ⟹ xa ∈ M ⟹ xb ∈ M ⟹ inv_into M η (η xa ⋅' η xb) = xa ⋅ xb
```

I tried to see what happens if I change `surjective` to `bijective` (among `using` requirements) and then I get slightly more simplified end result

```
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀x y. (⋀x y. x ∈ M ⟹ y ∈ M ⟹ η (x ⋅ y) = η x ⋅' η y) ⟹
           x ∈ M' ⟹
           y ∈ M' ⟹ ' = η  ⟹ inv_into M η (x ⋅' y) = inv_into M η x ⋅ inv_into M η y
```

But in the end `auto` can't do it. Interestingly, when I use `bijective` then the proof doesn't work even with the original definition of isomorphism.

MY DEFINITION 2:

I also get the same outcome if I define

```
locale monoid_homomorphism = monoid_morphism η  M "(⋅)"  M' "(⋅')" "'"
  for η and M and composition (infixl "⋅" 70) and unit ("")
    and M' and composition' (infixl "⋅''" 70) and unit' ("''")  +
  assumes commutes_with_unit: "η  = '"

locale monoid_isomorphism = bijective_map η M M' + monoid_homomorphism
```

MY DEFINITION 3:

It also doesn't work if I just split the definition into

```
locale monoid_homomorphism =
  source: monoid M "(⋅)"  + target: monoid M' "(⋅')" "'"
  for η and M and composition (infixl "⋅" 70) and unit ("")
    and M' and composition' (infixl "⋅''" 70) and unit' ("''") +
  assumes commutes_with_composition: "⟦ x ∈ M; y ∈ M ⟧ ⟹ η x ⋅' η y = η (x ⋅ y)"
    and commutes_with_unit: "η  = '"

text ‹Def 1.3›
text ‹p 37, ll 7--11›                              
locale monoid_isomorphism = bijective_map η M M' + monoid_homomorphism
```

Now it is not only logically equivalent, but it's actually syntactically equivalent if you just paste `monoid_homomorphism` into the definition of `monoid_isomorphism` (which I tried to do and it works).

```
locale monoid_isomorphism
  fixes η :: "'a ⇒ 'b"
    and M :: "'a set"
    and composition :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a"  (infixl ‹⋅› 70)
    and unit :: "'a"  (‹›)
    and M' :: "'b set"
    and composition' :: "'b ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'b"  (infixl ‹⋅''› 70)
    and unit' :: "'b"  (‹''›)
  assumes "monoid_isomorphism η M (⋅)  M' (⋅') '"
```

I tried to use `Query > Print Context` tab with all boxes ticked and the resulting contexts for the two definitions of this locale are exactly the same (syntactically).

I can't understand why such seemingly benign change would completely derail a proof.

I have uploaded the full code to
https://github.com/aleksander-mendoza/Isabelle

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be very simple. One definition was

```
assumes commutes_with_composition: "⟦ x ∈ M; y ∈ M ⟧ ⟹ η (x ⋅ y) = η x ⋅' η y"
```

while the other was

```
assumes commutes_with_composition: "⟦ x ∈ M; y ∈ M ⟧ ⟹ η x ⋅' η y = η (x ⋅ y)"
```

This has an important impact on `auto` and `simp` because they always try to match left side and replace the matched terms with right side.
In order to make the proof work it was enough to add `[symmetric]`

```
using commutes_with_composition[symmetric] commutes_with_unit surjective
```